# Using data types in an enum declaration

Tags: c, data-structures

Can I do something like this? I would like to use data types instead of constants in my enum `type_t`.

```
typedef struct {
    char id;
    long data;
} type1_t;

typedef struct {
    char id;
    long data;
    float moredata;
} type2_t;

typedef enum {
    type1_t, type2_t
} type_t;

typedef struct {
    type_t type;
    char* something;
} midas;

midas obj1;
obj1.type = type1_t;
obj1.type.id = 0;
obj1.type.data = 123;

midas obj2;
obj2.type = type2_t;
obj2.type.id = 3;
obj2.type.data = 456;
obj2.type.moredata = 3.14;
```

In the example the `type` variable of the `midas` struct should then refer to `type1_t` or `type2_t`. So if I set the type to `type2_t`, the size of it should be bigger than when I set `type1_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  If you were using C++, you could use templates to achieve this.  But there is no "type enum" mechanism in C.

You could consider a union:

```
typedef enum {
    type1, type2
} type_t;

typedef struct {
    type_t typecode;
    union {
        type1_t type1value;
        type2_t type2value;
    };
    char* something;
} midas;
```

This will cause `midas.type1value` and `midas.type2value` to occupy the same memory space.  The amount of memory taken for the union will be equal to the amount of memory required to store the largest data type it contains.

You would then have to look at `midas.typecode` and consider which union member to use.  If you use the wrong one you will wind up with invalid data and this may lead to program crashes, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks, that was a quick response! Isn't there a way to allocate memory for the `union`, or isn't that needed?

Comment: The memory is allocated as part of the `midas` struct itself.  The regions of memory used will just overlap, so you should only ever use one or the other for any given instance of the struct.  You can demonstrate this by asserting: `midas value; if (&(value.type1value) == &(value.type2value)) printf("The members are in a union.\n");`  You will see that pointers to each member of the union are equal in value.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The usual way to do something like this in C is with a union:

```
typedef enum { TYPE1, TYPE2 } type_t;

typedef struct {
    type_t type;
    union
    {
        type1_1 t1;
        type2_t t2;
    } u;
} midas;

midas obj1;
obj1.type = TYPE1;
obj1.u.t1.id = 0;
obj1.u.t1.data = 123;

midas obj2;
obj2.type = TYPE2;
obj2.u.t2.id = 3;
obj2.u.t2.data = 456;
obj2.u.t2.moredata = 31.14;
```

Comment: The union can be anonymous to avoid the `u.` everywhere.  Before that was widely supported it was common to have blocks of `#define t1_id u.t1.id`

Comment: @Ben Jackson: That's true, but that's not standard C, it's an extension to C provided by compilers.  If you want completely portable code, you should not use anonymous unions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `union`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that.  `enum`s are more or less equivalent to `int`s.

You can do this sort of thing was a union, e.g.:

```
typedef struct
{
    int   a;
    float b;
} type1_t;

typedef struct
{
    char  c;
    long  d;
} type2_t;

typedef union
{
    type1_t  t1;
    type2_t  t2;
} myUnion_t;


...

myUnion_t u;
u.t1.a = 3;
u.t1.b = 2.7f;
```

Answer (score 0):

That does not work. The closest thing would be to use a void* to your structure.